# May someone cordon of an area of a public place for his own use and not let others come within that area

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, real-estate

May someone cordon of an area of a public place for his own use and not let others come within that area.

1- May one make a show performance etc. in a public place and only allow people who pay to come?

2- May one make a large gathering for some people in a public place and keep others out?

3- May one stake out a place for a large picnic in a public place, and claim that other people who come within that area are disturbing his rightful use of that area?

May someone rope of a part of a public waterway for boat or swimming races, (or for recreational swimming or boating), and keep others from entering the waters there?

Comment: I can't fathom someone being allowed to prohibit the public entry into a public area unless he has been given a permit for private use. As for using picnic tables in a public park, there's an understood "first come; first gets" policy. You can't rope off your picnic area at will, though. Others are still allowed to pass through your picnic area.

Comment: +1 Your question is relevant only to הפקר places, not רשות היחיד and not רשות הרבים. To my understanding, there's no "unaffiliated public place" today, instead, the state administers all non-private areas in the country - maybe a sort of a שיתוף. As anything ממונות the use of those paces is a subject to the conditions all the people agreed on (דינא דמלכותא).

Comment: @DanF Just like i can stop others from sitting at the table where my family is sitting because it infringes on my right to use the public tables, how much area can i claim is an infringement of my own "right to use"?

Comment: @AlBerko I hope you dont mean רשות הרבים -היחיד as in shabbos. That is totally irrelevant here. In other areas reshus harabim means a public area, where everyone has rights to its use.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Why can 10 peple stand in a public place under the sky but the moment they put schach over their heads they become gazlonim??

Comment: Why can't you all bring it down to דינא דמלכותא - it all depends on what we previously agreed on as in all cases of ממונות.

Comment: "*Just like i can stop others...*" - depends exclusively on local laws. It could be all the way around - you can't stop anyone from sharing the table you occupied.

Comment: The Gemara (Bava Kamma) presents the principle of *avid inish dina lnafshei* (the ability to take the law into one's own hands, in a case where one filled a public place with his barrels-passersby are allowed to smash the barrels in order to pass with zero liability.  This of course may be subject to what the local norms are for that particular type of domain.

Comment: I thought that with all laws regarding Choshen Mishpat, the final answer is going to be *KeMinhag HaMedina* - it depends on local laws and customs. 

So  the answer to your question would be: it depends on where you live; call up the local municipality and ask them.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Not All laws in choshen mishpat go kminhag hamedinah. If in sedom they made someone pay someone who hit him and caused him to bleed, because the hitter did him a service of bloodletting, Is that ok because its minhag hamidinah"?

Comment: Even though there is an implied right to use the table for an indefinite amount of time, there is no written law stating that no one else can try to evict you from it. You can try to sue the other, but, I think you'd have a tough time winning the case based on an unwritten law. Public use of items and area don't seem to impose any specific protections against individual territorial rights. Applies to pool lockers, too. You can put your clothes in a locker, but it doesn't prevent someone else from moving your clothes to another one. Not nice to do, but legal, as far as I gather.

Comment: ribbis whether it's a good idea is not the same as whether it is enforceable, cc @danny

Answer (score -1):

*I decided to turn my comment into an answer:*

1. To my best knowledge, the Torah only recognizes one type of property -  private property (also הקדש which is Hashem's private property, and הפקר which is a lack of possession :). Private property can be shared between partners, but it is a Machlokes (source needed) whether each one owns a part of it, or both own the whole.
2. The status of what we call "Public places" is a very interesting issue, as Judaism does not truly recognize democracy especially in a Goyish country. But by the way of elimination, we can say: it is not a הפקר cause people cannot acquire it, not a הקדש, not a King's property, not a private property, but people can, in fact, use it - so it is a sort of a partnership.
   .
   *In ancient times some places outside of the towns **were** הפקר, but today all non-private property "belongs" to the state (correct me if I'm wrong).*
3. Use of shared property is subject to the original contract between the parties. In a democratic country that is the federal/provincial/municipal law, in our terms, it is דינא דמלכותא. The local people decide who will be officially in charge of managing all those places and that person(s) decide on permits. Those permits are Halachicly valid as דינא דמלכותא דינא.
4. Therefore, based on that, if the law allows one to cordon off an area **by a permit** - so be it, if it disallows - so be it. If it only allows that to a certain group of people (local taxpayers or LGTB or Jews) - so be it etc.
5. When you ask "can he keep other out", in our reality this is a basic idea behind the local Police force - to follow the local laws and guide the public accordingly. Of course, I can have a gun and not let others in, but that's not what you mean I suppose.

Comment: Only read through your first line, and it's already self-contradictory. Is it that the "Torah only recognizes one type of property", or many types of property, such as " הקדש which is Hashem's private property, and הפקר "? Also, dosn't look like your answer has any sources.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Does it answer the question? Yes. Does it explain why? Yes. Do you have anything that contradicts what I wrote? Write a better answer.

Comment: @AlBerko  You give no source at all for this "new type" of property status, other than dina demalchusa which does not always apply. If you concoct a completely new concept as an answer it is mandatory that you give sources.

Comment: @AlBerko You wrote "today all non-private property "belongs" to the state (correct me if I'm wrong)." You may be wrong. Under what halachic statute does it "belong" to the state? Also dina dmalchusa? If a state decides that they want to own a hefker property, dina dmalchusa gives them ownership rights??? source pleeeeease!

Comment: Don't kill the messenger. I said there's nothing new in partnership, however, it is not fully an ownership, as nobody can sell it or make it הפקר. Public places fall under federal/provincial/municipal kinds of partnership which are not explicitly covered by our Halacha. Judaism says almost nothing on running a city, let alone a country. It all goes under דינא דמלכותא.

Comment: Under a rule that תנאי בממון קיים managing common property is a subject to mutual agreement (similar to ז טובי העיר) - the city elects the 7 and they set the rules. Those rules obligates the members of the city as if they explicitly agreed on them - as long as it is all ממון.

Comment: I am truly sorry I can't bring sources. I don't work that way on general questions. You question, if I understand right is about outlining personal rights on common property, especially in a goyish city or country. Although I know the answer I don't recall anybody talking specifically on this topic. Also it seems absurd such a question remeins unanswered, so I decided to offer a true albeit an unsourced answer.

Comment: I don't understand why people dislike my answers (besides being unsourced) - does it contradict anything you know?

Comment: Besides for it sounding like conjecture, it's also internally contradictory. See what I wrote above. Another internal contradiction: in step 2 you write: "Judaism does not truly recognize democracy especially in a Goyish country" and in step 3 you write "a democratic country that is the federal/provincial/municipal law, in our terms, it is דינא דמלכותא". So which is it, do we recognize the government or don't we?